# Prove $\exists x (A(x) \to \forall y(A(y))$ is a theorem.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Working on P.D. Magnus. forallX: an Introduction to Formal Logic (pp. 297, exercise C. 4):

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{}{
 \fitch{\neg \exists x (A(x) \to \forall y(A(y))}{
 \fitch{¬A(c)}{
    \fitch{A(c)}{
     \bot\\
     \forall yA(y)\\
   } \\
   A(c) \to \forall yA(y)\\
   \exists x (A(x) \to \forall y(A(y))\\
   \bot\\
 }\\
 A(c)\\
 \ldots\\
 \bot
 }\\
 \exists x (A(x) \to \forall y(A(y))
}
$

Am I heading in the right direction? How can I fill the dots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subproof has so far derived that for *any* $c$ that $A(c)$ (under its assumption).

Therefore you may derive $\forall y~(A(y))$ by universal introduction under the assumption of $A(b)$ and *viola*.

So you should just tuck your subproof inside an *existential elimination* subproof and tie things up with a nice bot.

**Note:** The statement $\exists x~(A(x)\to\forall y~A(y))$ will be *vacuously false* in an empty domain, so let us take existential import to be an unstated premise. [We can not prove an existential when no thing exists.]

$$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{\exists x~x=x\hspace{20ex}\text{[existential import: the domain is non-empty]}}{\fitch{\neg\exists x~(A(x)\to\forall y~A(y))}{\fitch{[b]~b=b}{\fitch{A(b)}{\fitch{[c]}{\color{blue}{{\fitch{\neg A(c)}{\fitch{A(c)}{\bot\\\forall y~A(y)}\\A(c)\to\forall y~A(y)\\\exists x~(A(x)\to\forall y~A(y))\\\bot}\\\neg\neg A(c)\\A(c)}}}\\\forall y~A(y)}\\A(b)\to\forall y~A(y)\\\exists x~(A(x)\to\forall y~A(y))\\\bot}\\\bot}\\\neg\neg\exists x~(A(x)\to\forall y~A(y))\\\exists x~(A(x)\to\forall y~A(y))}
$$

---

It seems from the comments that P.D. Magnus book did not properly isolate local variables into their own contexts for use with its *existential elimination* and *universal introduction* rules.

Also Existential Import seems to be treated as a inference rule rather than a premise.   [In an non-empty domain, if everything satisfies a predicate, then something satisfies that predicate, so therefore $\exists x~P(x)$ may be inferred from $\forall x~P(x)$, or something to that effect.]

$$
\fitch{}{\fitch{\neg\exists x~(A(x)\to\forall y~A(y))}{{\fitch{A(b)}{{\color{blue}{{\fitch{\neg A(c)}{\fitch{A(c)}{\bot\\\forall y~A(y)}\\A(c)\to\forall y~A(y)\\\exists x~(A(x)\to\forall y~A(y))\\\bot}\\\neg\neg A(c)\\A(c)}}}\\\forall y~A(y)}\\A(b)\to\forall y~A(y)\\\forall x~(A(x)\to\forall y~A(y))\\\exists x~(A(x)\to\forall y~A(y))}\\\bot}\\\neg\neg\exists x~(A(x)\to\forall y~A(y))\\\exists x~(A(x)\to\forall y~A(y))}
$$

Comment: Note: Magnus' proof system *may* not require raising contexts for variables $b, c$, or require the existential elimination step ( existential import does seem to be considered axiomatic).  It has been a while.

Comment: Thank you very much, @GrahamKemp. Could you explain how did you derive $\forall xA(y)$ ? Isn’t $A(b)$ an undischarged assumption ?

Comment: What is an existential import ?

Comment: Existential Import is an axiom that **the domain is non-empty** (or that something exists), so that $\exists x~P(x)$ may be inferred from $\forall x~P(x)$.

Comment: *You* derived $A(c)$ for *any* $c$, under the assumption of $\neg\exists x~(A(x)\to\forall y~A(y))$, and thereby $\forall y~A(y)$ may be inferred by Universal Introduction.  The interim assumption of $A(b)$ may then be discharged by Conditional Introduction to derive $A(b)\to\forall y~A(y)$.

Comment: Perhaps, I am not fully familiar with your proof method, but are you using Universal introduction with $A(c)$? I see it is unavailable at that line. But probably, there is other reason behind it.

Comment: $A(c)$ was derived in the context of *arbitrary* variable $c$, so that context may be discharged to infer $\forall y~A(y)$. $$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{}{\fitch{~~5.~[c]}{~~~~\vdots\\14.~A(c)}\\15.~\forall y~A(y)\hspace{10ex}\forall\mathsf{Intro}~5{-}14}$$

Comment: As mentioned, perhaps your proof system does not *raise* contexts when you declare a new variables. As such perhaps your Universal Introduction resembles :$$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{}{~~~~\vdots\\14.~A(c)\\15.~\forall y~A(y)\hspace{10ex}\forall\mathsf{Intro}~14}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, @GrahamKemp ! Everything is clear, now.

Answer (score 0):

If $\forall y(A(y))$, then any $x$ will do.
If not, take some $x$ for which $A(x)$ is false.